# match() function not working for two vectors in r

Tags: r, match, matching

I'm trying to use the match function in function with a for loop and it isn't working. Here is an example of the exact error I'm getting.

```
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(2:11)
match(a,b)
```

It doesn't work. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error in match(a, b) : unused argument (b)
```

Then I tried something simpler:

```
match(2,a)
```

And it gives me this:

```
Error in match(2, a) : unused argument (a)
```

I really need this function for my code, can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: You must have some other function named `match` masking the default base function - either from some other package or of your own definition. You can specify `base::match(a, b)` to  make sure you get the right version, and check `conflicts(detail = TRUE)` to figure out where the masking version is coming from.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot replicate your phenomenon. I get the result `NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9` which looks alright to me. Could it be that the base function `match()` is masked by another package?

Comment: @GregorThomas - you were totally right. I create a function called match and that was the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: `rm(match)` will remove your version of `match` (and you can redefine it with a unique name)